# Mysql query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

whats wrong with the following sql? i have no idea at all

```
SELECT  `posts`.* 
FROM `posts`  
WHERE ((`posts`.`featured` = 1 OR `posts`.`author_id` = 5)) 
ORDER BY (ln( 1 + posts.likes_count) +  
         (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM posts.created_at) - 
          1327654606)/9000) desc LIMIT 15
```

thanks

Comment: Any errors or just empty dataset?

Comment: What errors are you getting or are the results just unexpected?

Comment: `EPOCH`is not valid in MySQL.

Comment: what is replacement for EPOCH..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EPOCH` is not valid in MySQL. Try replacing

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM posts.created_at)
```

with

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(posts.created_at)
```

to get the seconds of `posts.created_at` since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

See [MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)